# Changing datetime format without .ToString

Tags: c#, datetime

How to convert this:

```
2-1-2013 0:00:00
```

to this:

```
2/1/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Without converting to string? Or with converting to string, but the end result should be `DateTime`.

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format. The question is meaningless as it stands. What you've provided is a pair of *strings*.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You can't change the *string representation* of a datetime without using a *string*.

Comment: are you trying to get a datetime from 2-1-2013 0:00:00?

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` structure has not format meaning, format becomes important when you are going to display/output date time somewhere. So you can use `DateTime.ToString()` overloads to specify excat format you need to output.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion request has not much sence, as format is a *presentation* way of a data, and in this case that data is presented via string. You store `DateTime` into the object, but can *present* it in differen ways.

If you warry about seeing in `Watch` window, keep in mind that there it uses simple `DateTime.ToString(..).` with default culture of your application.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon has already mentioned, a `DataTime` has no inherent format, it has just a value. Strings have a format. So you need `DateTime.ToString` or `String.Format` to get your desired result:

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2-1-2013 0:00:00");
string result = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that i've used `ToString` to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to ensure that i get your desired AM/PM designator even in a culture which does not use it by default(as here in germany).

Comment: +1 for writing `here in Germany`on every answers about `CultureInfo` :)

Comment: @SonerGönül: I'm suprised that most questions and even many answers forget this fact, mentioned the country just to give an example.